# Cannot read the data of the certain document by its ID

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, err) in

self.logInButton.isLoading = false

// Check for errors
if err != nil {

// There was an error login to the system
self.showError("Incorrect login or password")
} else {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    // Here the program don't enter
    // In this case, complete shows the crossed out getDocument function
    db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (shapshot, error) in
    guard let snap = shapshot, error == nil else {
        self.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

I can't read the data although everything exists. When a program comes to getDocument, it just doesn't go into it.  What do I do wrong?

Upd.
Maybe, perhaps console output will help you somehow:

```
2020-03-15 07:35:37.919683+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39141] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60301000 started
2020-03-15 07:35:37.986973+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39141] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)
2020-03-15 07:35:37.992944+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39141] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-03-15 07:35:38.412739+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39185] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-03-15 07:35:38.809486+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39148] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800003] Registered an SDK that has already registered. Default flags will be overwritten. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-03-15 07:35:38.811448+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39148] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-03-15 07:35:39.585977+0500 SmartLibrary[1956:39134] 6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
```

Comment: Which *specific* line isn't being executed? if it's one of the two `guard` lines, then you have your answer.

Comment: db.collection(...).document(..).getDocument { ... }
I looked at the debug, the program simply goes directly to the line below, without even going into this closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the userId from the result:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, err) in

    if let uid = authResult?.user.uid { // successfully signed in

        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { (shapshot, error) in

            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                ...
            } else { // error with database

                if let error = error {
                    print(error) // print to console, find out why
                }

            }

        }

    } else { // error with login

        if let err = err {
            print(err) // print to console, find out why
        }

    }

}
```

If it still doesn't execute then you have a credentials issue and are either using the wrong email or password or the user in the admin itself doesn't exist or is disabled.

Get in the habit of printing to console as you code for immediate debugging.